# GPIO interrupts in alternate mode

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, gpio

Are the interrupts in GPIO module triggered (high to low edge, low to high edge, low level or high level) when GPIO is operating in alternate mode functionality?

Comment: Any particular architecture?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I don't have any particular architecture in mind. But i checked datasheets of few contoller's( raspberry pi & stm for ex) it looks like interrupts are triggered even when gpio pins are used for alternate functions.?

Comment: @UchiaItachi it reeeeeeeeeeeeaally depends on the architecture.  Suppose I made an architecture that has no interrupts on the GPIO module, then my answer to your question would be "No" regardless of the operating mode.

Answer (score 1):

Most microcontrollers that I have worked with so far (TI C2XXX, AD BlackFin, Microchip 12/18 and dsPICs, some ARMs) allow interrupt-on-change for some GPIO pins.  Those pins have to be configured correctly, of course.

Interrupts are based on change and such there is no interrupt source by staying in HI or LO state.  It is possible to periodically check for those states in a periodical interrupt or in the main while loop.  Careful- the while loop might have too high latency.  It all depends on your requirements.

In my field (power electronics & motor control) timing is critical.

Answer (score 0):

At least ARM architecture processors have registers to set interrupt behaviour. There is a separate register to mask the generated interrupts too: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0190b/I1002697.html Since the register is separate it is independent of the pin functionality.
I don't know if this is true for all architectures.